# Pulling out modification indices for variances of items with lavaan in R

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I've run a Multigroup CFA model with the package 'lavaan' in R and found that when running the strict invariance model the two groups were not invariant (not equal). This suggest that at least on one item the range is not the same for the two groups i'm comparing (boy, girl). To find out which item is the problem maker i asked for the modification indices. but to my surprise the `modindices()` function didn't show any variances since there wasn't anything like `x1 ~~ x1` in the dataframe `modindices()` created. It did give the modification indices for the covariances like `x1 ~~ x2`. Anyone any idea what i'm doing wrong (i used the latest version of lavaan)?

```
overall_model <- '
emotie    =~ e1 + e2 + e4 + e14 + e17 + e22 + e25
sociaal_1 =~ s1.5 + s1.16 + s1.24
sociaal_2 =~ s2.3 + s2.8 + s2.12 + s2.20
thuis     =~ t6 + t7 + t15 + t18 + t19 
lichaam   =~ l9 + l10 + l11 + l13 + l21 + l23
' 

strict_fit <- cfa(model = overall_model, 
                  data = df,
                  meanstructure = TRUE,
                  group = "gender",
                  group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts", "residuals"))

subset(modindices(strict_fit), op == "~~")
```

When i print out the (complete) modindices dataframe (with all possible "op" options, i also don't see all row numbers, it seems that it omits a lot of the paths from my model:

```
           lhs op   rhs block     mi      epc  sepc.lv sepc.all
1       emotie =~    e1     1  0.216   -0.070   -0.864   -0.042
8    sociaal_1 =~  s1.5     1  0.435    0.144    1.842    0.081
11   sociaal_2 =~  s2.3     1  0.004    0.016    0.143    0.007
15       thuis =~    t6     1  2.372    0.224    2.558    0.141
20     lichaam =~    l9     1  2.091    0.316    3.572    0.136
96      emotie =~    e1     2  0.297    0.083    1.348    0.058
103  sociaal_1 =~  s1.5     2  0.388   -0.136   -2.070   -0.086
106  sociaal_2 =~  s2.3     2  0.005   -0.019   -0.167   -0.009
110      thuis =~    t6     2  2.526   -0.231   -4.060   -0.180
115    lichaam =~    l9     2  2.295   -0.331   -5.842   -0.197
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: add `free.remove = FALSE` inside `modindices()` and you'll get all possible rows/modification indices.